# R - Doubly Censored Data Analysis

Tags: r, algorithm, survival-analysis

I am working on a small project in survival analysis and making use of the paper:

[Lagakos, De Gruttolla - Analysis of Doubly Censored Data, with applications to AIDS.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2497809)

Before implementing their code in R, I wanted to know if there were already packages that implement the method they describe. I am aware of the package [dblcens](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dblcens/index.html) however, it's functions use an EM algorithm rather than the algorithm described by Lagakos and De Gruttolla.

Has this algorithm already been implemented in some R package?

Thank you.

Comment: the paper is behind the paywall so might want to post the actual algorithm in your question. also, have you made any effort to code it yourself?

Comment: Or reach out to authors? I have had fabulous luck asking people if the make unofficial libraries!

Comment: Thanks epo3. I can code it myself; however, I was interested in whether the algorithm was already available. It was a 1976 paper with it's dataset available in the dblcens package so I figured the algorithm may already be implemented elsewhere; however, I cannot find it. Depending on the response of this thread, I may just have to code it up myself.